# Change Color Property when Drawing an Ellipse?

Tags: delphi, canvas, drawing

Hi I am trying to figure out how to change the color of an ellipse when drawing it on a form. My code is below.

```
procedure TForm3.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if ssalt in shift then
     form3.canvas.Ellipse(x-10,y-10,x+10,y+10)
  else
     if ssCtrl in shift then
        form3.canvas.Ellipse(x-10,y-10,x+10,y+10);    
end;
```

I know that an ellipse has a brush.style property when using the tshape component, but I can't seem to figure out how to change it for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The color of the interior is determined by `Canvas.Brush.Color`.
2. The perimeter will be drawn in the color specified by `Canvas.Pen.Color`.

You will also need to make sure the Set `Canvas.Brush.Style` is set appropriately, e.g. to `bsSolid` and likewise for `Canvas.Pen.Style`, e.g. `psSolid`.

The documentation for [`TCanvas.Ellipse`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Graphics.TCanvas.Ellipse) states it like this:

> The ellipse is outlined using the value of Pen, and filled using the value of Brush.